# Setfattr always returns operation not supported

Tags: files, xattr

I'm trying to get a script working however I'm having issues with a particular line trying to set file attributes with setfattr.

The line in question is

```
ret=os.system('setfattr -n "user.dummy" -v "dummy" /apachelogs/data/file')
```

The fstab output of this location is as follows.

```
/dev/sdb1 /apachelogs          reiserfs    user,noauto,rw,exec,suid,user_xattr        0       2
```

Returns the error message:

```
setfattr: /apachelogs/data/file: Operation not supported
```

Can anyone give me any advice on what I might be doing wrong? My google-fu is only telling me that the problem usually occurs when someone doesn't prefix user on the first variable.

Cheers.

Comment: So, we're supposed to guess that this is python, running on Linux, being run as root, that the file exists etc etc? Quite apart from being off topic here (were you looking for [so]?), we need more info to answer. Does the command work when run manually for example?

Comment: How did you mount it? `mount /apachelogs` (right) or `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /apachelogs` (wrong)?

Comment: I'm answering this to point the way for anyone having trouble with seeing extended attributes in KDE, particularly using btrfs. There's no solution I know of, since having "baloo" (strange name) installed doesn't provide Dolphin with the desired interface. So the (hopefully temporary) solution in this case is to use the shell's "getfattr" and "setfattr" commands as demonstrated above by @slm.

Comment: Try "attr -s" .

Answer (score 4):

Things to try.

#### 1. Does the path exist?

I know it sounds silly but make sure that the directory `/apachelogs/data` exists. Also make sure that the file exists, `/apachelogs/data/file` and that you have permissions to manipulate it.

#### 2. Try the commands from a shell

I would confirm that the above commands can work in a shell directly before attempting to do them from Python.

#### Example

Try the following:

```
$ cd /apachelogs/data
$ touch foobar
```

Now add the extended attribute:

```
$ setfattr -n user.foo -v bar foobar
$ getfattr -d foobar
# file: foobar
user.foo="bar"
```

#### References

- [setfattr always returns "Operation Not Supported"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-source-2.6.15/+bug/43954)

Comment: `reiserfs` does support `xattr`s though. That's more a comment than an answer.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - it is borderline comment/A. If the OP provides more info I'll gladly delete this.

Comment: If the path didn't exist, you'd get a ENOENT error message (like _No such file or directory_), not ENOTSUP. `pythons`'s `system()` does call a shell (`sh`, `-c`, `the-string`).

Comment: Above we have used user namespace, please someone, guide me on how to use system namespace of Extended Attributes.